# Recent Blogspot Update Breaks window.getSelection() for Web Extension. Any Suggested Work Arounds?

Tags: javascript, blogger, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a Firefox Extension, [bbCodeWebex](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/bbcodewebex/), which automates bbCode, and HTML codes through a context menu.

About 2 weeks ago, some sort of change was made to the HTML editing window which broke this code:

```
let currentSelection = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
```

Previously, this would return the content of the selected text, and now it returns `​<empty string>` in the console.

It works in the WYSIWYG editing window, and works everywhere else that I've checked, but not in the HTML editing window.

Clearly Google has done something with the HTML Editing window that messes with this function.

Any suggestions as to how to determine what this is or how to work around this problem.

(*on edit*)
I think that I may have found a solution in a text to speech program called Native Text to Speech -TTS uses this call to get selected text and read it aloud:

```
  browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {  
    tabId = tab.id;  
    menuId = info.menuItemId;  
    console.log(menuId)  
    texT = info.selectionText;  
    browser.tabs.sendMessage(  
  ………
  });
```

I am unsure how this call works though.

Comment: The question would be much easier to answer if you link to the demo page. I guess they might have switched to an iframe.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

It's on the editing pages for Blogger, so you have to log in to access them with a Blogger account.

Comment: Ok, I've sound a solution that a FF screen reader uses, I'm unclear as to what is happening at a program level.

Native Text to Speech -TTS uses this call to get selected text:

    browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {  
       tabId = tab.id;  
       menuId = info.menuItemId;  
       console.log(menuId)  
       texT = info.selectionText;  
       browser.tabs.sendMessage(  
      ………
      });  


I don't quite get the notation, so I'm not sure how this works, and if there would be a drop in to replace window.getSelection in my extension.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why, or how Google broke `window.getselection`, but it turns out that `document.activeElement.value` works, so I've added a case where if `window.getselection`is empty or undefined or null, to use `document.activeElement.value`.

Thanks, Google.